# Getting input from within same element jquery

Tags: jquery, input, fadein, siblings

I'm really starting to get to grips with jQuery, however i keep getting stuck on a small problem.

I need to fadeIn a input type button when focussing on a text input sitting in the same parent:

```
<span class="newsFeedMaxAutoLoad">
    <span title="This is number of news ite....">
         auto display:
    </span>
    <input type="text" onfocus="setAutoNews(this);" value="10" maxlength="99" class="newsAutoInput">
    <input type="button" value="save" class="button green small newsAutoSave"><!-- this is hidden by default by its class 'newsAutoSave'-->
</span>
```

The jQuery i am attempting to achieve this:

```
function setAutoNews(obj){
   var objParent = $(obj).parent();
   $(objParent + ' .newsAutoSave').fadeIn();
}
```

But in return i keep getting the same error:

> Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object Object]

Would anyone be able to tell me how i can fadeIn the input button when focussing on the text input? I think i'm missing a fundamental here but can't put my finger on it.

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//find the elements we want to bind to for the focus event
$('.newsFeedMaxAutoLoad').children('.newsAutoInput').on('focus', function () {

    //select the next element which is the button,
    //we could also use `.siblings('.newsAutoSave')` instead of `.next()` if the button may not always be the exact next sibling element
    $(this).next().fadeIn(250);
});
```

This avoids using inline JS which makes maintaining the code a lot easier. So your HTML would look like this:

```
<span class="newsFeedMaxAutoLoad">
    <span title="This is number of news ite....">
         auto display:
    </span>
    <input type="text" value="10" maxlength="99" class="newsAutoInput">
    <input type="button" value="save" class="button green small newsAutoSave"><!-- this is hidden by default by its class 'newsAutoSave'-->
</span>
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ZzHx3/

Comment: This actually makes the most sense of all I guess. Start the event listener at the top instead of traversing up and down like a monkey. Thank you very much! I'm actually continually having a constant battle with a friend of mine as to which is better, inline event listeners or this method. The bottom line to me is that, 1000 inline onclicks is a lot more data transfered between client and server when a single event listener can be added to the script file as you have done. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to concatenate an object with a string.

`objParent` is a jQuery object. You could do this instead:

`objParent.find('.newsAutoSave').fadeIn();`

Also it is somewhat of a common practice to prefix your variable names with a `$` if they are jQuery objects. This makes it easier for you to remember that you are working with a jQuery object instead of a string or regular DOM node.

You could change your code to the following:

```
function setAutoNews(obj){
   var $objParent = $(obj).parent();
   $objParent.find('.newsAutoSave').fadeIn();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would probably take a different approach and not create the function at all:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('.newsAutoInput').click(function() {
    $(this).next('.newsAutoSave').fadeIn();
  });
});
```

Comment: Ahhh... next. I didn't know about that one. So that just grabs the next element in the parent... nice. Thanks a lot! :)